# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{(1-\tan\frac{\pi}{2})(1-\sin x)}{(1+\tan\frac{\pi}{2})(\pi-2x)^3}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Evaluate $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{(1-\tan x)(1-\sin x)}{(1+\tan x)(\pi-2x)^2}$

Question about this..
Shouldn't the answer be infinity..as I have read $x$ as $\frac{\pi}{2} + h$ where..$h$ tends to zero..

Comment: Please use MathJax to format expressions https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: tan(pi/2) does not exist!

Comment: It won't be infinity since there is $ tan(π/2) $ in both the numerator and denominator. Use $ (1 - tan(π/2))/ (1 + tan(π/2)) = tan(π/4 - π/2) = -1 $

Comment: @InternetGuy that is not correct. $\tan(\pi / 2)$ is simply undefined, since you are dividing by $\cos(\pi / 2) = 0$. Putting it in both numerator and denominator does nothing to change this fact. The limit, as phrased now, is not defined and therefore nonsense

Comment: Are you sure the limit you are evaluating isn't $\lim_{x \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{(1-\tan(x))(1-\sin(x))}{(1+\tan(x))(\pi-2x)^3}$ ?

Comment: This problem is misstated in the title. Please correct it.

Comment: $\tan x \sim \frac{1}{\pi/2 - x}$ as $x \to \frac{\pi}{2}$; and $\sin x = 1 - \frac{1}{2} (x - \frac{\pi}{2})^2 + O((x - \frac{\pi}{2})^4)$ as $x \to \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

If the limit you want to solve is $\lim_{x \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{(1-\tan(x))(1-\sin(x))}{(1+\tan(x))(\pi-2x)^3}$, then you could evaluate it in the following way;
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{(1-\tan(x))(1-\sin(x))}{(1+\tan(x))(\pi-2x)^3}=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{(1-\tan(x+\frac{\pi}{2}))(1-\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{2}))}{(1+\tan(x+\frac{\pi}{2}))(-8x^3)}
$$
using the trigonometrical identity $\sin(a+b)=\sin a \cos b+\sin b \cos a$;
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{(1-\tan(x+\frac{\pi}{2}))(1-\cos(x))}{(1+\tan(x+\frac{\pi}{2}))(-8x^3)} \sim \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{(1-\tan(+\frac{\pi}{2}))}{(1+\tan(x+\frac{\pi}{2}))(-16x)}
$$
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos(x+\frac{\pi}{2})-\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{2})}{(\cos(x+\frac{\pi}{2})+\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{2}))(-16x)}=\pm \infty
$$
In fact the limit doesn't exist, since you get $+ \infty$ from the right and $- \infty$ from the left.

Comment: Actually there is no limit, you get $+\infty$ from the right, $-\infty$ from the left.

Answer (score 0):

I'll use the expression in the question rather than the one in the title, because the latter is meaningless, as $\tan\frac{\pi}{2}$ is undefined.

The hint is good, but probably it's better to use
$$
x=\frac{\pi}{2}-t
$$
so
$$
\tan x=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-t\right)=\cot t
\qquad
\sin x=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-t\right)=\cos t
$$
and $\pi-2x=2t$, so your limit becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{(1+\cot t)(1-\cos t)}{4t^2(1-\cot t)}
$$
Recalling that $\cot t=\frac{1}{\tan t}$ you can transform the limit into
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{(1+\cot t)(1-\cos t)}{4t^2(1-\cot t)}
=
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\tan t+1}{\tan t-1}\frac{1-\cos t}{4t^2}
$$

Answer (score -1):

As we have
$$\frac{1-\tan (x)}{1+\tan (x)}=\frac{\cos (x)-\sin (x)}{\sin (x)+\cos (x)}\to -1,\text{ as } x\to\frac{\pi}{2}$$
we can write the limit as 
$$\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi }{2}} \, \frac{\sin (x)-1}{(\pi -2 x)^2}$$
using L'Hopital rule twice we get the limit that is $-\dfrac{1}{8}$